# Android launch Twitter intent

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

I used below code for launching Twitter through intent but it's not working. I have twitter app installed on my phone.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content to share");
PackageManager pm = contexto.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
    if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        contexto.startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Getting exception when I try to calling the activity:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.twitter.android/com.twitter.android.PostActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception? try putting your code in try catch and see if there is some error.

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.twitter.android/com.twitter.android.PostActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?  DO I NEED TO PUT SOMETHING IN THE ANDROID MANIFEST???

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Typically for launching a user's feed

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    // get the Twitter app if possible
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=USERID"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no Twitter app, revert to browser
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/USERID_OR_PROFILENAME"));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

For Post Intent

```
Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a Test.");
tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");

PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent,  PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

boolean resolved = false;
for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo: resolvedInfoList){
    if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.twitter.android")){
        tweetIntent.setClassName(
            resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, 
            resolveInfo.activityInfo.name );
        resolved = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(resolved){
    startActivity(tweetIntent);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter app isn't found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Slightly corrected (thanks to Taranfx) an user's feed intent (change **user_id**=>**screen_name**):

```
    public static void startTwitter(Context context) {

    Intent intent = null;
    try {
        // get the Twitter app if possible
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=<place_user_name_here>"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return intent;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // no Twitter app, revert to browser
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/<place_user_name_here>"));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is it! The old `?userId=` is not working anymore

Answer (score -1):

I was using the `com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity` to post text and images since 2016. But started to receive crash reports from users some time ago:

> Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException Unable to
> find explicit activity class
> {com.twitter.android/com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity};
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

The issue was caused by renaming
`com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity`
to
`com.twitter.composer.ComposerActivity`
inside Twitter app.

The issue was resolved since I changed activity name to `com.twitter.composer.ComposerActivity`.

And I use the following code to post images with text to Twitter:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
    .setText(getTextToShare())
    .setStream(getImageUriToShare())
    .setType("image/png")
    .getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    .setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.composer.ComposerActivity");
```