# How can I send a tweet with Android by calling already installed Twitter App?

Tags: android, twitter

How can I send a tweet with Android without using CONSUMER_KEY and/or CONSUMER_SECRET? **I do not want to show a dialog with share options** (as we can see in Share Intent)

My desired scenario is to click in a button that then shows a dialog to the user, with the message to be tweeted. This dialog is just a dialog from Twitter App already installed in the device.

Architecturally speaking, Android need to call Twitter App, sending parameters to it, and Twitter App shows a dialog with the tweet to be sent. The desired behavior is like the ShareDialog/OpenGraph from Facebook SDK.

Comment: are you looking for an intent? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088250/android-launch-twitter-intent

Comment: Thank you asiviero! The second approach from the answert was just I was looking for

Comment: Also look at this -http://stackoverflow.com/a/14317559/4671372