# Security Exception : Permission Denial on posting to Twitter

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to post on twitter using below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        if (app.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(PACKAGE_TWITTER)) {
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strBody);
            intent.setComponent(name);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
```

And this code throws security exception. Please help.

Comment: Post Exception Log as well

Comment: @kapsym java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] typ=text/plain flg=0x10200001 cmp=com.twitter.android/.composer.ComposerActivity clip={text/plain T:} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{3745232 4862:com.et.reader.activities/u0a219} (pid=4862, uid=10219) not exported from uid 10135

Comment: Why do you need intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

Comment: You dont need the launcher category. Remove that line of code. Follow this link to make it work - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088250/android-launch-twitter-intent

Comment: The link you mentioned, i am already using that code. But this code gives exception on Marshmallow and above devices.

Comment: did you try after removing the launcher line

Comment: Yes i have tried with that. Still giving exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set android:exported="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml file where you declare this Activity.

```
<activity
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
      </action>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I am trying to post on twitter. How can i set android:exported="true" for Twitter activity.