# packageManager.queryIntentActivities: Check if resolved app is a browser

Tags: android

On Android, I'm using `packageManager.queryIntentActivities` to return a list of apps that can handle a URL.

I only want to open the URL in an app that is specifically meant for that URL, i.e. the `Twitter` app for twitter urls, but I don't want to open the URL using a generic browser like `Chrome` or `Firefox`.

Is there a way to check if the returned app is specifically meant for that URL or if it's a generic browser?

Comment: Add your intent details

Answer (score 0):

Example from [Android launch Twitter intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088250/android-launch-twitter-intent) .

The key lies in URI schemes.

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    // get the Twitter app if possible
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no Twitter app, revert to browser
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/USERID_OR_PROFILENAME"));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, but `twitter` was just an example, the url can be anything.